# The limit of a division of two sequences is equal to the limit of the division of their series (under conditions)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm having a hard time solving an analysis problem. I tried really hard to find an answer online, I have downloaded numerous solutions manual for the book that proposed this question but I could not find it solved anywhere.
Let $y_n$ be a sequence of non zero positive numbers and let the limit of its series be $+\infty$. Then, for any sequence $x_n$, if there is some real number $a$ so that $\lim{x_n/y_n}=a$, we have

$\lim{\sum x}/{\sum y}=a$

The problem above was phrased using a concise notation, which I see myself obliged to clarify (not the problem, but the convenience of the notation).

Let's start by noting the obvious: the problem deals with sequences and series, which are also sequences. If a sequence has a limit, can this limit mean anything else than the value of the sequence as the indexes of its terms become greater and greater? If it cannot, than there is no need to explicit $+\infty$ as an index of the limit.

Now, as for the sum symbol in the expression $\lim{\sum x}/{\sum y}=a$, indeed I have taken for granted that, in the context of series and sequences, $\sum x$ could mean nothing else than the series of a sequence whose elements are named in general x, in particular $x_n$.

As I was first made aware of a possible flaw in my proposing the problem, I have reviewed it many times, and I come to the same conclusion: my notation is different than others, but in no way less precise.

Comment: If the question is not well asked, we cannot give an answer and it could be downvoted.

Comment: I'm sorry if I failed in asking correctly the question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I did some minor changes, please let me now if the question is now better formulated

Comment: indeed there was a limit symbol missing

Comment: Use the hypothesis to argue $x_n\approx ay_n$, from which the result follows. (You need to make it precise.)

Comment: I wonder if this hypothesis would work equally under the following conditions: $x_n$ goes to infinity, $a=0$, $\lim{x_n}=0$ or/and $\lim{y_n}=0$

Comment: For example, suppose $x_n=1/(n^2)$ and $y_n=1/n$. I don't see how $x_n\approx ay_n$ would be of any help.

Comment: Furthermore, the question is quite easy to solve if there are non zero real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim{x_n}=a$ and $\lim{y_n}=b$

Comment: This is my best reading of the intent: Let $(y_n)$ be a positive real sequence such that $\sum_{n} y_{n} = \infty$. If $a$ is real and $(x_n)$ is a real sequence such that $x_n/y_n\to a$, then$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^N x_n}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^N y_n}=a.$$Not downvoting yet, but as the question is current written, I would say this is not clearly stated. If this reading is correct, could you please edit the question to include these details?

Comment: ok, I now understand how (some?) people of this community would like to see the problem phrased. I respect their attachment to indexes, but I find it much more elegant, intelligible and not in the least ambiguous my writing without the indexes. I think indexes should always be left unwritten if they can be understood by context. Please feel free to downvote or downgrade the question. Furthermore, if these indexes are so important to you, feel also free to amend the question.

Comment: by the way, usually I would write $\lim{x/y}=a$ once it was understood x and y were representing sequences